# Play video one after another using a SurfaceView and two MediaPlayer objects

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to play different videos one after another, like a stream. Without 1 sec delay when switching video. I used `SurfaceView` and `MediaPlayer`.

If I use one `MediaPlayer` and change video it works fine but with a little delay in switching video. That's why I'm using 2 `MediaPlayer` objects - when 1 is playing other is preparing. But when I start it then the surface does not show video.

Here is my code:

```
vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);  
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mediaPlayer2.setDataSource(path2);

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //start next video here

                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer=null;               
                try {
                    mediaPlayer2.start();                       
                }
                catch(Exception e){}
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer2.prepare();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
    mediaPlayer2.setDisplay(vidHolder);

    //setup
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //start playback
}
```

Comment: any luck solving this problem i have the exact same issue

Comment: sorry i cant find anything.